# set jest to connect to test database

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

hi guys working on an existing project which has jest setup on it but its not specifying to run in the test database, just ran tests and it messed up my dev db. What do I need to do specify that it should run the test database called "test"? All I have is the package.json which says:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "verbose": true,
    "bail": true,
    "roots": [
      "./tests"
    ]
  },
```

No tests setup file exists, I'd rather use a setup file than the package.json

Comment: note the database is a postgresql db

Answer (score 1):

Running tests against a dedicated test database that is separate from the development database is a good idea. To make it happen, you need to externalize database connection strings from project source code. Before running any tests, you need to set up the externalized configuration so that your app will connect to the right database.

The exact answer depends on how you externalize the connection strings. One option is to use the 12-Factor App way of using environment variables to pass configuration. Assuming also, that you have [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or similar library that reads `.env` files. You'd read `.env.test` at the start of your `jest.config.js`. It'd set up the test database connection that different from your development time `.env` file.

Remember that `.env` files shouldn't be committed to version control.

Comment: thanks for the reply. there is a dotenv file setup, however it does not seem to pick up the test db when running npm run test (./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBand), the .env file contains constants for both dev and test e.g. DEV_DB_NAME TEST_DB_NAME

Comment: in your test command, you might need to pass env using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env just like
`cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest`